# How did the Covenant accidentally stumble over David's signal?

Tags: plot-explanation, alien-covenant

In a scene in *Alien: Covenant*, Covenant is en route to a world to colonize when the accident interrupts the voyage. They detect a signal from the planet close by and off they go exploring.

This seems quite an unbelievable coincidence to me. I mean, even if they knew of the fate of the Prometheus how can they 'accidentally' stumble onto the the engineer planet?

There is no way they could know that David and Shaw had gone off to find it. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: "Can anyone explain this?" Yeah, bad writing.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good example of [The Contrived Coincidence](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ContrivedCoincidence), and maybe a bit of [Because Destiny Says So.](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BecauseDestinySaysSo)

> Contrived Coincidence describes a highly improbable occurrence in a story which is required by the plot, but which has absolutely no outward justification

The other canon explanation may be that Weyland-Yutani already knew where they were, or atleast the general direction and just happened to send the crew (and many others) that direction, knowing they’d find David and or the engineers...assuming they found any sort of signal, as it was company policy to investigate any such signals, alien or otherwise.

This was also the plot point in Alien and Aliens.

Comment: That seems unlikely. If the Weyland corporation knew of the engineer's world they could have simply sent some military expedition, or use a crew of androids like David. There is every likelihood the Prometheus adventure was known, but at the end of the Prometheus movie it's obvious that Shaw and David had to leave not knowing the location of the engineer planet at that time but intent on seeking it out. It is a VERY contrived coincidence. Prometheus and Alien:Covenant are packed to the gills with such coincidences.

Comment: As i said, its possible they knew more than they let on...Weyland-Yutani is a company full of conspiracy this is shown it all the diffferent media lores...i dont think they did, and its why i said that its a contrived coincidence...but then again, thats usually what all movies like this are...but they wouldnt send drones...they cost money...human life is valueless to W-Y...dont forget special order 937....